# Underscore.js Grouping Object

Tags: json, underscore.js

is it posible to group object and combine all properties with Underscore.js like this:

```
[
    { menu: "Setting", role: "admin" },
    { menu: "Setting", role: "user" },
    { menu: "Setting", role: "developer" },
    { menu: "Application", role: "admin" },
    { menu: "Application", role: "user" },
]
```

into something like this:

```
[
    { menu: "Setting", admin: "OK", user: "OK", developer: "OK"},
    { menu: "Application", admin: "OK", user: "OK"},
]
```

Comment: Yes, it's also possible with regular old JS, too.

Comment: yes, i've been trying with regular JS, but i end up with for loops that taking time and memory, so i would like looking for alternatives like underscore.js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.map(_.groupBy(arr, 'menu'), function(roles, menu) { 
  var entry = {menu: menu};
  _.each(roles, function(role) { entry[role.role] = "OK"; });
  return entry;
})
```

I'm assuming the output you are after is:

```
[
  { "menu": "Setting", "admin": "OK", "user": "OK", "developer": "OK" }, 
  { "menu": "Application", "admin": "OK", "user": "OK" } 
]
```

Comment: woaah, it works with such a simple script. thanks for your answer. :D